# Tomcat vs Websphere's web container performance

Tags: performance, tomcat, websphere

Anybody knows about a performance comparison for Tomcat vs Websphere app server's web container?

[www.webperformanceinc.com](http://www.webperformanceinc.com) provides such a comparison but it's very outdated, somebody knows if there is a newer one, say with Websphere v6.1 or v7?

Answer (score 0):

Websphere uses Tomcat under the hood. It only adds some more Java EE capabilities (EJB and so on) and of course the IBM sausage over it, so I wouldn't expect Websphere to be much faster than Tomcat.

Comment: WAS does not use tomcat under the hood. It does use some code but tomcat is not the web container that is used by WAS.

JBoss or WebSphere CE (Geronimo) use tomcat as the web container.

In general, Tomcat is probably the most efficient web container (as it is lean and mean) but WAS provides a number of other features which might appeal if you want a full fledged JEE server.

Comment: When i refer to some code, i am referring to code base from the ASF which is also used by Tomcat (either built as part of Tomcat or as part of the other ASF projects)